# Report object in Apex

Tags: apex

I'm trying to query the report object and put it in the list for later computation. But i'm not able to assign it to the list. But if i use query editor in "Dev Console" then it'll fetch results. ( Even i changed to generic sObject[] and try to cast it back it'll show name and id as unidentified )

[image]

Comment: Do you have a class named 'Report' in your salesforce org?

Comment: @MohithKumar Thanks...i should've checked...thanks for the tip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that your Apex Code's "version" setting is set high enough. Older versions of Apex Code didn't have access to the Report object. Use the "Versions" tab to control which version you are compiling against. Unless you have a strong reason not to, I recommend changing your code to v29.0. Also, if you have a class named Report, you must explicitly use Schema.Report instead of just Report:

```
Schema.Report[] reportList { get; set; }
```

You do not need to specify Schema in your query, however:

```
reportList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Report ...];
```

Comment: My bad!!! I should have checked it first...There was a class with name Report..Thanks